# Accessing File system from SharePoint - Access denied

Tags: c#, file, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, access-denied

I've created a custom SharePoint application which extends some of the OOTB functionality of SharePoint. Now I want to license the application and provide trial periods etc. So I want to store the licensing information in the file system/registry and check the validity of the license across the application. But even after I elevate to the application pool identity (who is just a domain user and not a system administrator as advised here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863%28office.12%29.aspx) I'm getting access denied for accessing my file.

What is the common practice to read/write/create files in the file system from SharePoint application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no other solution apart from storing it in a custom database or a custom folder which is configured with full access for the application pool account.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked thet security logs to see which user is being denied access.  I am pretty sure it will be the user who is logged into sharepoint rather than the app pool identity that is trying to access the file. The app poolidentity is usually only used in this way if the web site is using anonymous authentication.

Comment: I'm sure it is the application pool. I can even understand why. Check the technet article I've mentioned and see the file system permissions for WSS_WPG in which the app pool identity is a member. It doesn't have full control on any of the folder.

Comment: That is a very long and boring article so I have only skimmed it ;-)  I can't see anything in it that contradicts what i said.  I am not sharepoint expert but standard asp.net web apps will access the file system as the windows user that is authenticated if windows integrated authentication is eanbled, they will use the app pool identity if for example anon authentication is enabled.

Comment: But the app pool identity has to have the write access to the file system. Right? Not all the windows users have the write access. Even in ASP.NET application only if the application pool identity is having the full control over the entire file system (which is not highly recommended) he can access the files. By telling access I mean read/write/delete. SharePoint automatically grants some permissions to a windows user if he is used as an app pool identity. And he doesn't have write permission on most of the file system.

Comment: And you have to read atleast "Other application pool accounts" to understand what I'm saying. :)

Comment: The section "Other application pool accounts" does not in any way relate to the point I am making.  Access to files and folders is determined by standard NTFS file permissions, on a normal web app using windows integrated authentication, by default, when a file is accessed via the website then the windows user account of the website user is used and not the app pool identity.  SharePoint may not work this way, i am not 100% sure.  The fact that the app pool identity requires some level of write access to some areas of the file system is irrelevant in the case you have outlined.

Comment: Sorry. I guess you don't understand how SharePoint works in this regard. Not all the information workers are going to have access to the file system. They are just end users who use the application. But our custom sharepoint add-ons sometimes need to access the filesystem/sharepoint database. In this case we normally elevate the user context to the application pool identity programatically and access the resources. This is because app pool is given 'certain' permissions by SharePoint when you create a web application. Unfortunately the permissions to the file system is very limited.

Comment: Whatever I've mentioned above is the standard practice of giving permissions. No sys admin will be assigned as application pool identity because any malformed injected code will have access to the entire universe. So I'm just trying to figure out how to achieve licensing of my application by storing the licensing file 'somewhere'.

Comment: OK I understand now, sorry i don't think I have been much help :-(

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SharePoint 2010 or 2007? What kind of Authentication? NTLM, Forms or Claims based?

If application is running under NTLM, then as Ben suggested, application will run under NTLM account and you should be able to access the resource.

If running under forms the application will run as anonymous user (local account), which will fail to access the shared resource.

I would suggest using ProcMon, it will capture the underlying access denied error and what user is being used to access that.